# Play 2.0 doesn't run all tests

Tags: java, testing, junit, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm porting an application over to Play 2.0 and for some reason it's not running all the tests. It finds all the test classes. But just doesn't run any tests in most of them. I tried moving the classes to the base of tests directory, but that didn't make a difference.

The tests it doesn't run contain tests for the persistence using hibernate JPA. The classes have a common base class for managing the database state across tests.

I'm expecting the persistence tests to blow up spectacularly but right I just get a green light because it doesn't run any of the tests in them.

Comment: did you adapt the tests to use Play 2.0 support methods?

Comment: Never heard of the support methods, are those the ones on the helper class? I'm just trying to get it run the methods annotated with @Test.

Comment: please add snippets of code showing your test methods and your project layout, otherwise we can't give an answer

Comment: Eventually found the cause. A @BeforeClass method was throwing an exception. Would be nice if it actually reported this as a failed test, not as 0 out 0 tests run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer my own in case someone else trips in to this.

If you have a failing setup step, say @BeforeClass annotated method throws an exception, then Play will report the test case as 0 out of 0 tests run.