# Play Framework (2.1.3) doesn't run any tests

Tags: java, junit, playframework

I have 4 test classes with an average of two test functions each. The first test is below and must be correct (its from Play's tutorial).

```
public class ApplicationTest {

    @Test 
    public void simpleCheck() {
        int a = 1 + 1;
        assertThat(a).isEqualTo(2);
    }

}
```

The other ones are custom made and have a `@Before` setup, like this:

```
public class UserTest extends WithApplication {

@Before
public void setUp() {
    start(fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase()));
}

// creation and retrieval of user
@Test
public void createAndRetrieveUser() {
    new User("bob@gmail.com", "Bob", "secret").save();

    User bob = User.find.where().eq("email", "bob@gmail.com").findUnique();

    assertNotNull(bob);                 // successfully retrieved
    assertEquals("Bob", bob.getName()); // correct user retrieved
}
}
```

Now when I run `play test` it finishes a lot quicker and doesn't execute any test.

```
PS C:\wamp\www\dcid> play test
[info] Loading project definition from C:\wamp\www\dcid\project
[info] Set current project to dcid (in build file:/C:/wamp/www/dcid/)
[info] Compiling 4 Java sources to C:\wamp\www\dcid\target\scala-2.10\test-classes...
[info] ApplicationTest
[info]
[info]
[info] Total for test ApplicationTest
[info] Finished in 0.014 seconds
[info] 0 tests, 0 failures, 0 errors
[info] models.UserTest
[info]
[info]
[info] Total for test models.UserTest
[info] Finished in 0.002 seconds
[info] 0 tests, 0 failures, 0 errors
[info] models.ProposalTest
[info]
[info]
[info] Total for test models.ProposalTest
[info] Finished in 0.002 seconds
[info] 0 tests, 0 failures, 0 errors
[info] Passed: : Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0, Skipped 0
[success] Total time: 5 s, completed 16/Ago/2013 14:52:35
```

**Why is this? What can I do?**
I recently updated from play 2.1.2 to 2.1.3. I updated all references and the project is working fine, except the tests.
I also [looked at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548953/play-2-0-doesnt-run-all-tests), but it can't be that, since I didn't change my tests, so they are well written, it's just their execution that is not working.

Comment: You should add java tag to allow the format to kick in and have a bit more of view on your question ;)

Comment: Nice tip, I didn't know about it, done ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's [a known issue of Play 2.1.3](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/Jn9k6osk6V0). Meanwhile there is [a workaround](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/Jn9k6osk6V0).
Add the following into Build.scala file in the val main function:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
  // Add your own project settings here      
  testOptions in Test ~= { args =>
    for {
      arg <- args
      val ta: Tests.Argument = arg.asInstanceOf[Tests.Argument]
      val newArg = if(ta.framework == Some(TestFrameworks.JUnit)) ta.copy(args = List.empty[String]) else ta
    } yield newArg
  }
)
```

Comment: Helped me a ton .. Me a newbie to play f/w