# Play Framework 2.4 (Java) not running all unit tests

Tags: playframework

**Problem Description**

I'm having trouble getting "activator test" to run all my tests. I have a few test files (5 at the moment). Let's call them:

dir1\subdir1\ClassOneTest.java
dir1\subdir2\ClassTwoTest.java
dir1\subdir2\ClassThreeTest.java
dir1\subdir2\ClassFourTest.java
dir1\subdir2\ClassFiveTest.java

When I run "activator test" (and others...like ~testQuick), only four of them run (say "One" thru "Four"). "Five" does not run. I refactor>rename "Five" to "Six" and it still does not run.

I first suspected my test code, so I removed all meaningful tests and replaced with simple `assertTrue(false)` or `assertTrue(true)`. I even removed annotations like @RunWith or @FixMethodOrder. Still, the problem remained.

I then tried swapping file names. If I switch names with "Five" and "Four", then the new "Four" runs, and the new "Five" does not run. So it seems that the problem relates to file discovery, not the code in it. Note: "Five" and "Four" are in the same directory.

I also tried applying the suggestion given out for Play 2.1 to `build.sbt`
(link: [Play Framework (2.1.3) doesn't run any tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18275638/play-framework-2-1-3-doesnt-run-any-tests)). All that did was mute the `[info] Test ... started` info, but no additional tests were discovered.

**Question**

I've run out of ideas. Does anyone have suggestions I could try?
If you need specific code examples/config settings, please specify and I will try to accommodate.

**A little more info**:
- Some test files become discovered and ran if I changed the source. Other test files, not so lucky.
- Using IntelliJ Ultimate 15.0.2
- The test directory structure follows that of the project 
- Current build.sbt has:

`javaOptions in Test += "-Dlogger.file=conf/logback.xml"`
`testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "-q", "-v")`

Comment: Strange. What happens if you add a new one, like `Six`, so you have 6 of them? Does the `Six` run, skipping `Five` or is it just the first four. Of course, I do not expect in any way it is related with numbering.

Comment: Tried that before; `Six` does not run. Just now I moved all files out of `test`, created some new files, and none of them ran. I think the ones that did run were classes that I made a while back. None of the new ones are running. Even if I move all the previous test files back into `test`, none of them run now. Even `ApplicationTest` and `IntegrationTest` do not run. I will look over my config file again...

Comment: One test class that I did not move out of `test` continues to pass with a simple `assertTrue(true)` test. I duplicated that test file, gave it a new name. The new test file will not run. So far it points to new test classes not being discovered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try, in the activator console, `clean` then `compile` and then try running your tests again.
It could sound very obvious but it might work.